# Keeping java sockets open - how to check if new data available?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a simple client-server application using sockets for the communication. One possibility is to close the socket every time the client has sent something to the server.

But my idea is to keep the connection always open, i.e. if a client contacts the server the connection should be put into a queue (e.g. LinkedBlockingQueue) and kept open, this would increase the performance.

How can I check in the server if there is new data available in a socket in the queue? The only thing I can imagine is to constantly iterate over the whole queue and check every socket if it has new data. But this would be very inefficient because if I have several threads working on the queue, the queue gets blocked when one thread is scanning over it.

Or is there a possibility to register a callback function on the socket, so that the socket informs the threads that data is ready?

Comment: The socket's InputStreams have several read methods that block the current thread until something is available. You usually need to do socket networking multithreaded. That means have a receiving thread for each client that stores the data somewhere the main thread can retrieve it when needed. (comment because not sure if this was the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my idea is to keep the connection always open, i.e. if a client contacts the server the connection should be put into a queue (e.g. LinkedBlockingQueue) and kept open, this would increase the performance.

Keeping connections open will improve performance, though there are scaling issues: an open socket uses kernel resources.  (I wouldn't use a queue though ...)

> How can I check in the server if there is new data available in a socket in the queue?

If you have a number of sockets to different clients, and you want to process data in (roughly) the order that it arrives, there are two common techniques:

- Create a thread per socket, and have each thread simply do a read.  This will (naturally) block the thread until data becomes available.
- Use the NIO channel selector mechanism (see [`Selector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html)) which allows you to find out which of a group of I/O channels is ready for a read or write.

Thread per socket tends to be resource hungry (thread stacks), and does not scale well at all if you have multiple threads that are active simultaneously.  (Too many context switches, too much load on the thread scheduler.)

By contrast, selectors map onto native syscalls provided by the host operating system, and thus they are efficient and responsive ... if used intelligently.

(You could also obtain non-blocking channels for the sockets, and poll them round-robin fashion.  But that isn't going to be either efficient or responsive.)

As you can see, none of these ideas work with a queue.  Either you have a number of threads each dealing with one socket, or you have one thread dealing with an array or (array) list of sockets.  The queue abstraction is not designed for indexing or iterating.

> Or is there a possibility to register a callback function on the socket, so that the socket informs the threads that data is ready?

See @Lolo's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let's say I have a thread which is created when the socket thread accepts a connection. When the thread now puts the connection on a queue and then the thread terminates, will this also close the connection?

Answer (score 0):

A practical solution would be to use NIO2 [AsynchronousSocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html)s to perform asynchronous read operations with a callback that you can specify as a [CompletionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/CompletionHandler.html).